# How to make a Label visible for a certain time and then should be invisible with JavaFX?

Tags: time, label

i'm asking about how can i make a label visible for a certain time( 3 or 5 seconds) and then this label should be invisble after the ending of the time with JavaFX. So please which methode or which something does that ? and thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) and hide the label when the pause finishes.

```
PauseTransition visiblePause = new PauseTransition(
        Duration.seconds(3)
);
visiblePause.setOnFinished(
        event -> label.setVisible(false)
);
visiblePause.play();
```